# Overloading function template based on lambda arguments

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am trying to create a function where callers can pass in lambdas with a certain set of known parameters (the return type can be anything the caller wants)
Let's say the possible lambda signatures are

1. T (Widget*)
2. T (Widget2*)

I've tried a couple things but I can't get any of them to work

```
struct Widget2{
    int count = 0;
};

class Widget {
public:
template<typename Fn, typename T = std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Widget*>>
T doIt(Fn&& fn)
{
    return fn(_sibling);
}

template<typename Fn, typename T = std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Widget2*>>
T doIt(Fn&& fn)
{
    return fn(_other);
}

private: 
Widget* _sibling = nullptr;
Widget2* _other = nullptr;
};
```

I've also tried doing something like this

```
template<typename Fn>
auto doIt(Fn&& fn)
{
    if (std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Widget*>)
        return fn(_sibling);
    else if (std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Widget2*>)
        return fn(_other);
}
```

this code in a compiler: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wMAuw5XXnc0zTjlk

I'd rather avoid having to add multiple functions like doItWidget1, doItWidget2 and so on.

Is there a way I can basically overload functions based on the arguments of the incoming lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enable_if` to sfinae away the wrong overload

```
template<typename Fn, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Widget*>, int> = 0>
auto doIt(Fn&& fn)
{
    return fn(_sibling);
}

template<typename Fn, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Widget2*>, int> = 0>
auto doIt(Fn&& fn)
{
    return fn(_other);
}
```

Note that you don't even need to figure out the return type `T`, you can just use `auto` to do that.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PW55n4GM3).

Comment: Simpler: `template<typename Fn> std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Widget*>> doIt(Fn&& fn)`, which triggers the SFINAE as well, but is simpler and isn't bypassable.  Or `template<typename Fn> auto doIt(Fn&&fn) -> decltype(fn(_sibling)) {return fn(_sibling);}`, or `template<typename Fn> auto doIt(Fn&&fn){return fn(_sibling);}` depending on your compiler version

Comment: this is perfect. I was hoping the compiler would figure out the type if I specified it in the template explicitly. I'm curious as to why  `template<typename Fn, typename T = std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Widget*>>
T doIt(Fn&& fn)`, fails, but replacing T with the same value works `std::invoke_result_t<Fn, Widget*> doIt(...)` works.